# NativeWind/TailWindCSS not being applied correctly when running web version on react native expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, tailwind-css

I am using NativeWind for my CSS in my React Native Expo project, but the styling is not being applied on the web version. Also the image is not being shown on the web version. The styling works fine and the image shows up when I run it on my Iphone and I am curious why it is not being applied to the web version. I used NPM to install webpack and think I have all the necessary dependencies. When compiling the web version I get a DeprecationWarning -

(node:30960) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_CONSTRUCTOR] DeprecationWarning: Using 'compiler' as the first argument is deprecated. Please use 'options' as the first argument and 'compiler' as the second argument.

(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:30960) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_LISTEN] DeprecationWarning: 'listen' is deprecated. Please use the async 'start' or 'startCallback' method.

web compiled successfully

This is my tailwind.config.js -

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*/.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is my webpack.config.js -

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
  // Customize the config before returning it.
  return config;
};
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the web version to be styled correctly? Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: May be unrelated, but one your content paths has an extra `/`. Should be `"./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",`

Comment: Hi @Adam Terhaerdt, did you find the answer to this, I have the same issue!! , it works well on my expo ios version (physical device) but not on expo web :(

Answer (score 0):

What webpack are you using, as Expo Web does not support Webpack 5?

Have you run the [Tailwind guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) guide or checkout their example on [example guide](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/tree/next/examples/expo) - check their webpack.config.js, styles.css and App.tsx, because it seems like, you are missing some things